# Livewire is not working without PHP artisan serve

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

When I use `php artisan serve`, Livewire is working fine.

[image: Screenshot here]

When I use XAMPP (http://localhost/daily/public/) to view Laravel, Livewire is not working, it keeps submitting the form when I submit. It should not submit because of Livewire. It is working fine in `php artisan serve`. Livewire is not working XAMPP.

[image: (http://localhost/daily/public/) Screenshot here]

Comment: Do you get any messages in the browser's console?

Comment: Its possible that your `APP_URL` in `.env` is set to `127.0.0.1`, perhaps?

Comment: My console is showing livewire.js not found,.

Comment: @BenzigarJS Is the `livewire.js` file in `public` folder?

Comment: I have the same issue and couldn't find the answer yet...

Answer (score 3):

First of all you should publish livewire configurational file with next command:

```
php artisan livewire:publish --config
```

Then in config folder you would be able to find file htdocs\YourProjectName\config\livewire.php where you would be able to edit the next string:

```
'asset_url'  => null,
```

to

```
'asset_url'  => 'http://localhost/YourProjectName/public',
```

And it should work after that. At least it worked in my case.

Docs: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/installation

But in docs that string is called:

```
'asset_base_url' => '/assets'
```

instead of

```
'asset_url'  => 'http://localhost/YourProjectName/public',
```

But in the end it doesn't matter;)

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that is is not working (Out of the box) in Laragon too.

While using it with 'php artisan serve' the url http://livewire.test/counter was correctly loaded from /public while within Laragon it was not. I suspected it having to do something with Xampp and Laragon using virtual domains.

After changing APP_URL to http://livewire.test/public it did not work either, but after a reload of Apache within Laragon it finnaly did.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are on Windows. Consider switching to laragon. The thing just works